# iOS OpenAL Sound is not positional

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, audio, openal

Ok, here's my problem.

I'm working on some helper classes, that capsulate OpenAL functionalities on iOS for me. Right know, it's working quite well, that means I can play multiple sounds (at the same time) and configure there gain and pitch.

The next step for me is to add positional sounds. I know, that I have to use properties for the listener's position and the sources' positions (and velocity but that's not so important right know).

The problem is, that I implemented everything corresponding to tutorials on the internet, but the sound is always not attenuated, so it isn't positional.

I found out, that sometimes this is caused by stereo audio files, so now I'm using mono files, but the problem still arises. In fact, I downloaded this [example project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenALExample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003587) from apple. It is for Mac OS and does work. So I took the sound files from their project and used them in my own. So there should be no problem with sound format. It still doesn't play back positional.

So my question is:
Is it possible to play back sound positional with OpenAl on the iPhone?
And if yes, what are the minimum  OpenAL properties that should be set to realize 3D playback? Maybe I'm just not setting one basic setting that is needed.

Also, I thought the simulator is the problem, but when I tested my app on a really iPhone, it doesn't work, either.

I will know add my current code here, but I think it's too much to find the bug directly. I'm hoping for someone who knows a standard solution for my annoying problem (which, I think, will be some little mistake :D )

So here's the code:

Listener:

```
class Listener {
    private:
    vec3    position;
    vec3    velocity;
    vec3    at;
    vec3    up;
public:
    Listener();

    void setOrientation(vec3 at, vec3 up);

    vec3 getPosition();
    void setPosition(vec3 position);

    vec3 getVelocity();
    void setVelocity(vec3 velocity);
};

Listener::Listener() {
    alListenerf(AL_GAIN, 0.5f);
    alDistanceModel(AL_INVERSE_DISTANCE_CLAMPED);
}

void Listener::setOrientation(vec3 at, vec3 up)
{
    printf("Listener Set Orientation\n");
    ALfloat *orientation = (ALfloat*)malloc(6*sizeof(ALfloat));
    orientation[0] = at.x;
    orientation[1] = at.y;
    orientation[2] = at.z;
    orientation[3] = up.x;
    orientation[4] = up.y;
    orientation[5] = up.z;
    alListenerfv(AL_ORIENTATION, orientation);
    this->at = at;
    this->up = up;
    free(orientation);
}

vec3 Listener::getPosition()
{
    return position;
}

void Listener::setPosition(vec3 position)
{
    printf("Listener Set Position\n");
    ALfloat *positionArray = (ALfloat*)malloc(3*sizeof(ALfloat));
    positionArray[0] = position.x;
    positionArray[1] = position.y;
    positionArray[2] = position.z;
    alListenerfv(AL_POSITION, positionArray);
    this->position = position;
    free(positionArray);
}

vec3 Listener::getVelocity()
{
    return velocity;
}

void Listener::setVelocity(vec3 velocity)
{
    printf("Listener Set Velocity\n");
    ALfloat *velArray = (ALfloat*)malloc(3*sizeof(ALfloat));
    velArray[0] = velocity.x;
    velArray[1] = velocity.y;
    velArray[2] = velocity.z;
    alListenerfv(AL_VELOCITY, velArray);
    this->velocity = velocity;
    free(velArray);
}
```

Sample

```
class Sample {
private:
    UInt32  usageCount;         // Number of Screens using this sound
    const   char *filename;     // The Filename, should be unique!
    ALuint  audioBuffer;        // The sound buffer in which it is stored
public:
    Sample(const char* filename);
    Sample(std::string);

    void    load();
    bool    unload();

    std::string getFilename();
    ALuint  getAudioBuffer();
};

Sample::Sample(const char* filename)
{
    usageCount = 0;
    this->filename = filename;
}

Sample::Sample(std::string filename)
{
    usageCount = 0;
    this->filename = filename.c_str();
}

void Sample::load()
{
    ALenum  format;
    ALvoid* data;
    ALsizei size;
    ALsizei freq;

    if (usageCount == 0) {
        data = SampleLoader::GetOpenALAudioData(filename, &size, &format, &freq);

        // Generate Buffer
        alGenBuffers(1, &audioBuffer);

        // Fill Buffer With Data
        alBufferData(audioBuffer, format, data, size, freq);

        // Free Audio Data
        if (data)
        {
            free(data);
            data = NULL;
        }
    }

    usageCount++;
}

// returns true, if usageCount got zero
bool Sample::unload()
{
    if (usageCount == 1) {
        // Delete Buffer
        alDeleteBuffers(1, &audioBuffer);
        return true;
    }

    usageCount--;
    return false;
}

std::string Sample::getFilename()
{
    std::string strFilename = std::string(filename);
    return strFilename;
}

ALuint Sample::getAudioBuffer()
{
    return audioBuffer;
}
```

Source

```
class Source {
    vec3        position;
    vec3        velocity;
    vec3        direction;
    ALfloat     gain;
    ALfloat     pitch;
    ALuint      sourceID;
    Sample      *sample;
public:
    void load();
    void unload();

    ALboolean   isPlaying();

    void play();
    void repeat();
    void stop();

    void updateSample(Sample *sample);
    void updatePosition(vec3 position);
    void updateVelocity(vec3 velocity);
    void updateDirection(vec3 direcation);
    void updateOrienation(vec3 position, vec3 velocity, vec3 direction);
    void updateGain(ALfloat gain);
    void updatePitch(ALfloat pitch);
};

void Source::load()
{
    alGenSources(1, &sourceID);

    position = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    velocity = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    direction = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_POSITION, value_ptr(position));
    alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_VELOCITY, value_ptr(velocity));
    alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_DIRECTION, value_ptr(direction));

    gain = 0.5f;
    pitch = 1.0f;

    alSourcef(sourceID, AL_GAIN, gain);
    alSourcef(sourceID, AL_PITCH, pitch);
}

void Source::unload()
{
    alDeleteSources(1, &sourceID);
}

ALboolean Source::isPlaying()
{
    ALint sourceState;
    alGetSourcei(sourceID, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &sourceState);
    return (sourceState == AL_PLAYING);
}

void Source::play()
{
    alSourcei(sourceID, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE);
    alSourcePlay(sourceID);
}

void Source::repeat()
{
    alSourcei(sourceID, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);
    alSourcePlay(sourceID);
}

void Source::stop()
{
    alSourceStop(sourceID);
}

void Source::updateSample(Sample *sample)
{
    alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, sample->getAudioBuffer());
}

void Source::updatePosition(vec3 position)
{
    alSource3f(sourceID, AL_POSITION, position.x, position.y, position.z);
}

void Source::updateVelocity(vec3 velocity)
{
    alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_VELOCITY, value_ptr(velocity));
}

void Source::updateDirection(vec3 direction)
{
    alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_DIRECTION, value_ptr(direction));
}

void Source::updateOrienation(vec3 position, vec3 velocity, vec3 direction)
{
    alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_POSITION, value_ptr(position));
    alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_VELOCITY, value_ptr(velocity));
    alSourcefv(sourceID, AL_DIRECTION, value_ptr(direction));
}

void Source::updateGain(ALfloat gain)
{
    alSourcef(sourceID, AL_GAIN, gain);
}

void Source::updatePitch(ALfloat pitch)
{
    alSourcef(sourceID, AL_PITCH, pitch);
}
```

The Sample Loader Function, taken from the project from apple

```
void* SampleLoader::GetOpenALAudioData(const char* filename, ALsizei *outDataSize, ALenum *outDataFormat, ALsizei*  outSampleRate)
{
    OSStatus                        err = noErr;
    SInt64                          theFileLengthInFrames = 0;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription     theFileFormat;
    UInt32                          thePropertySize = sizeof(theFileFormat);
    ExtAudioFileRef                 extRef = NULL;
    void*                           theData = NULL;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription     theOutputFormat;

    // Create Path
    NSString *filenameString = [NSString stringWithCString:filename encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *components = [filenameString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[components objectAtIndex:0] ofType:[components objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
    CFURLRef inFileURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)audioFileURL;

    // Open a file with ExtAudioFileOpen()
    err = ExtAudioFileOpenURL(inFileURL, &extRef);
    if(err) {
        printf("MyGetOpenALAudioData: ExtAudioFileOpenURL FAILED, Error = %d\n", (int)err);

        // Dispose the ExtAudioFileRef, it is no longer needed
        if (extRef) ExtAudioFileDispose(extRef);
        return theData;
    }

    // Get the audio data format
    err = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(extRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &thePropertySize, &theFileFormat);
    if(err) {
        printf("MyGetOpenALAudioData: ExtAudioFileGetProperty(kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat) FAILED, Error = %d\n", (int)err);

        // Dispose the ExtAudioFileRef, it is no longer needed
        if (extRef) ExtAudioFileDispose(extRef);
        return theData;
    }
    if (theFileFormat.mChannelsPerFrame > 2)  {
        printf("MyGetOpenALAudioData - Unsupported Format, channel count is greater than stereo\n");

        // Dispose the ExtAudioFileRef, it is no longer needed
        if (extRef) ExtAudioFileDispose(extRef);
        return theData;
    }

    // Set the client format to 16 bit signed integer (native-endian) data
    // Maintain the channel count and sample rate of the original source format
    theOutputFormat.mSampleRate = theFileFormat.mSampleRate;
    theOutputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = theFileFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;

    theOutputFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    theOutputFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2 * theOutputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    theOutputFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    theOutputFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2 * theOutputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    theOutputFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    theOutputFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;

    // Set the desired client (output) data format
    err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(extRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(theOutputFormat), &theOutputFormat);
    if(err) {
        printf("MyGetOpenALAudioData: ExtAudioFileSetProperty(kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat) FAILED, Error = %d\n", (int)err);

        // Dispose the ExtAudioFileRef, it is no longer needed
        if (extRef) ExtAudioFileDispose(extRef);
        return theData;
    }

    // Get the total frame count
    thePropertySize = sizeof(theFileLengthInFrames);
    err = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(extRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames, &thePropertySize, &theFileLengthInFrames);
    if(err) {
        printf("MyGetOpenALAudioData: ExtAudioFileGetProperty(kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames) FAILED, Error = %d\n", (int)err);

        // Dispose the ExtAudioFileRef, it is no longer needed
        if (extRef) ExtAudioFileDispose(extRef);
        return theData;
    }

    // Read all the data into memory
    UInt32 theFramesToRead = (UInt32)theFileLengthInFrames;
    UInt32 dataSize = theFramesToRead * theOutputFormat.mBytesPerFrame;;
    theData = malloc(dataSize);
    if (theData)
    {
        AudioBufferList     theDataBuffer;
        theDataBuffer.mNumberBuffers = 1;
        theDataBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = dataSize;
        theDataBuffer.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = theOutputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
        theDataBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData = theData;

        // Read the data into an AudioBufferList
        err = ExtAudioFileRead(extRef, &theFramesToRead, &theDataBuffer);
        if(err == noErr)
        {
            // success
            *outDataSize = (ALsizei)dataSize;
            *outDataFormat = (theOutputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame > 1) ? AL_FORMAT_STEREO16 : AL_FORMAT_MONO16;
            *outSampleRate = (ALsizei)theOutputFormat.mSampleRate;
        }
        else
        {
            // failure
            free (theData);
            theData = NULL; // make sure to return NULL
            printf("MyGetOpenALAudioData: ExtAudioFileRead FAILED, Error = %d\n", (int)err);

            // Dispose the ExtAudioFileRef, it is no longer needed
            if (extRef) ExtAudioFileDispose(extRef);
            return theData;
        }       
    }

    // Dispose the ExtAudioFileRef, it is no longer needed
    if (extRef) ExtAudioFileDispose(extRef);
    return theData;
}
```

SoundManager

```
namespace SoundManager {
    extern ALCdevice *openALDevice;
    extern ALCcontext *openALContext;

    extern std::vector<Sample*> samples;

    void initialize();
    void release();

    Sample* manage(const char* filename);
    Sample* manage(std::string filename);
    void remove(Sample *sample);
}

namespace SoundManager {
    ALCdevice *openALDevice;
    ALCcontext *openALContext;

    std::vector<Sample*> samples;
}

void AudioInterruptionListenerCallback(void* user_data, UInt32 interruption_state)
{
    if (kAudioSessionBeginInterruption == interruption_state)
    {
        alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    }
    else if (kAudioSessionEndInterruption == interruption_state)
    {
        AudioSessionSetActive(true);
        alcMakeContextCurrent(SoundManager::openALContext);
    }
}

void SoundManager::initialize()
{
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, AudioInterruptionListenerCallback, NULL);

    UInt32 session_category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(session_category), &session_category);

    AudioSessionSetActive(true);

    // Open Device
    openALDevice = alcOpenDevice(NULL);

    // Create and activate context
    openALContext = alcCreateContext(openALDevice, NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(openALContext);
}

void SoundManager::release()
{
    // Give up Context and destroy it
    alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    alcDestroyContext(openALContext);

    // Close device
    alcCloseDevice(openALDevice);
}

Sample* SoundManager::manage(const char* filename)
{
    return manage(std::string(filename));
}

Sample* SoundManager::manage(std::string filename)
{
    if (samples.size() >= kMaxNumberOfSamples) {
        Engine::warning("Max number of samples reached! Release one first");
        return NULL;
    }

    // If Sound is already managed, load the managed again
    for (int i=0; i<samples.size(); i++) {
        if (samples[i]->getFilename().compare(filename) == 0) {
            printf("Already loaded\n");
            samples[i]->load();
            return samples[i];
        }
    }

    // Otherwise load the new sound and manage it
    printf("Load new sound\n");
    Sample *sample = new Sample(filename);
    sample->load();
    samples.push_back(sample);
    return sample;
}

void SoundManager::remove(Sample *sample)
{
    for (int i=0; i<samples.size(); i++) {
        if (samples[i]->getFilename().compare(sample->getFilename()) == 0) {
            // If Sound isn't in use from anywhere else, unmanage it
            if (samples[i]->unload()) {
                samples.erase(std::remove(samples.begin(), samples.end(), sample), samples.end());
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    Engine::warning("The sound to be removed wasn't managed!");
}
```

So right here, this are all wrapper classes for the Source, Buffer and Listener, and a manager, which just ensures, that a Sample is only loaded once. All this is applied in a screen class, which gets rendered in my simple Engine. It's independent and should just play back a sound, which moves from left to right and back. But it doesn't:

```
class SoundTestScreen : public Screen
{
private:
    void initialize();
    void load();
    void unload();

    void update(Time &time);
    void draw(Time &time);

private:
    Listener listener;
    Sample *bubbles;
    Source *bubbleSource;

    double totalTime;
    double lastPlayTime;
};

void SoundTestScreen::initialize()
{    
    listener.setPosition(vec3(0, 0, 0));
    listener.setVelocity(vec3(0, 0, 0));
    listener.setOrientation(vec3(0, 0, -1),vec3(0, 1, 0));

    totalTime = 0;
    lastPlayTime = 0;

    // Create Sources to play the samples
    bubbleSource = new Source();
}

void SoundTestScreen::load()
{
    // Only load sample once
    bubbles = SoundManager::manage("sound_electric.wav");

    bubbleSource->load();
    bubbleSource->updateSample(bubbles);
    bubbleSource->updatePosition(vec3(0,0,0));
    bubbleSource->repeat();
}

void SoundTestScreen::unload()
{
    // Only unload sample once
    SoundManager::remove(bubbles);

    bubbleSource->unload();
}

void SoundTestScreen::update(Time &time)
{   
    bubbleSource->updatePosition(vec3(100*sinf(time.ElapsedTime),0,0));
}

void SoundTestScreen::draw(Time &time)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

This all is just some basic implementation, but I really don't know why the sound is not positional.

I really hope someone can find my mistake, it's very annoying.

Greetings

---

EDIT:

It's working now, there was only some small mistake I corrected now, but didn't find for long time.
I'll leave this code up for someone who is searching for some example iOS sound system for OpenAL which is rare on the internet, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, you brought down the thunder when it came to giving example code! :D

So the code that I learned from that was positional was thus:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <AL\al.h>
#include <AL\alc.h>
#include <AL\alut.h>

// Maximum data buffers we will need.
#define NUM_BUFFERS 3

// Maximum emissions we will need.
#define NUM_SOURCES 3

// These index the buffers and sources.
#define BATTLE      0
#define GUN1        1
#define GUN2        2

// Buffers hold sound data.
ALuint Buffers[NUM_BUFFERS];

// Sources are points of emitting sound.
ALuint Sources[NUM_SOURCES];

// Position of the source sounds.
ALfloat SourcesPos[NUM_SOURCES][3];

// Velocity of the source sounds.
ALfloat SourcesVel[NUM_SOURCES][3];


// Position of the listener.
ALfloat ListenerPos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

// Velocity of the listener.
ALfloat ListenerVel[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

// Orientation of the listener. (first 3 elements are "at", second 3 are "up")
ALfloat ListenerOri[] = { 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };


/*
* ALboolean LoadALData()
*
*   This function will load our sample data from the disk using the Alut
*   utility and send the data into OpenAL as a buffer. A source is then
*   also created to play that buffer.
*/
ALboolean LoadALData()
{

    alutInit (NULL, NULL);

    //ALUT allows us to point to a buffer object using an ALuint.
    // furthermore, there are calls that allow you to load from memory.
    Buffers[BATTLE] = alutCreateBufferFromFile("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Desktop\\OpenAL\\OpenALStaticSound\\wavdata\\Battle.wav");
    Buffers[GUN1] = alutCreateBufferFromFile("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Desktop\\OpenAL\\OpenALStaticSound\\wavdata\\Gun1.wav");
    Buffers[GUN2] = alutCreateBufferFromFile("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Desktop\\OpenAL\\OpenALStaticSound\\wavdata\\Gun2.wav");

    // Bind the buffer with the source.
    //alGenSources (1, &Source);
    alGenSources(NUM_SOURCES, Sources);

    //Attach any special modifications to the source
    //alSourcei (Source, AL_BUFFER,   Buffer   );
    //alSourcef (Source, AL_PITCH,    1.0      );
    //alSourcef (Source, AL_GAIN,     1.0      );
    //alSourcefv(Source, AL_POSITION, SourcePos);
    //alSourcefv(Source, AL_VELOCITY, SourceVel);
    //alSourcei (Source, AL_LOOPING,  AL_TRUE  );

    alSourcei (Sources[BATTLE], AL_BUFFER,   Buffers[BATTLE]  );
    alSourcef (Sources[BATTLE], AL_PITCH,    1.0              );
    alSourcef (Sources[BATTLE], AL_GAIN,     1.0              );
    alSourcefv(Sources[BATTLE], AL_POSITION, SourcesPos[BATTLE]);
    alSourcefv(Sources[BATTLE], AL_VELOCITY, SourcesVel[BATTLE]);
    alSourcei (Sources[BATTLE], AL_LOOPING,  AL_TRUE          );

    alSourcei (Sources[GUN1], AL_BUFFER,   Buffers[GUN1]  );
    alSourcef (Sources[GUN1], AL_PITCH,    1.0            );
    alSourcef (Sources[GUN1], AL_GAIN,     1.0            );
    alSourcefv(Sources[GUN1], AL_POSITION, SourcesPos[GUN1]);
    alSourcefv(Sources[GUN1], AL_VELOCITY, SourcesVel[GUN1]);
    alSourcei (Sources[GUN1], AL_LOOPING,  AL_FALSE       );

    alSourcei (Sources[GUN2], AL_BUFFER,   Buffers[GUN2]  );
    alSourcef (Sources[GUN2], AL_PITCH,    1.0            );
    alSourcef (Sources[GUN2], AL_GAIN,     1.0            );
    alSourcefv(Sources[GUN2], AL_POSITION, SourcesPos[GUN2]);
    alSourcefv(Sources[GUN2], AL_VELOCITY, SourcesVel[GUN2]);
    alSourcei (Sources[GUN2], AL_LOOPING,  AL_FALSE       );



    return AL_TRUE;
}

/*
* void SetListenerValues()
*
*   We already defined certain values for the Listener, but we need
*   to tell OpenAL to use that data. This function does just that.
*/
void SetListenerValues()
{
    alListenerfv(AL_POSITION,    ListenerPos);
    alListenerfv(AL_VELOCITY,    ListenerVel);
    alListenerfv(AL_ORIENTATION, ListenerOri);
}

/*
* void KillALData()
*
*   We have allocated memory for our buffers and sources which needs
*   to be returned to the system. This function frees that memory.
*/
void KillALData()
{
    alDeleteBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, &Buffers[0]);
    alDeleteSources(NUM_SOURCES, &Sources[0]);
    alutExit();
}


int main(){


    printf("Original Tutorial : MindCode's OpenAL Lesson 1: Single Static Source\n\n");
    printf("Updated Tutorial : Lesley A. Gushurst\n");

    alutInit(NULL, 0);
    //alGetError();

    // Load the wav data.

    if(LoadALData() == AL_FALSE)
    {
        printf("Error loading data.");
        return 0;
    } else {
        // Begin the battle sample to play.
        alSourcePlay(Sources[BATTLE]);

        // Go through all the sources and check that they are playing.
        // Skip the first source because it is looping anyway (will always be playing).
        ALint play;

        while (!_kbhit())
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < NUM_SOURCES; i++)
            {
                    alGetSourcei(Sources[i], AL_SOURCE_STATE, &play);

                    if (play != AL_PLAYING)
                    {
                        // Pick a random position around the listener to play the source.

                        double theta = (double) (rand() % 360) * 3.14 / 180.0;

                        SourcesPos[i][0] = -float(cos(theta));
                        SourcesPos[i][1] = -float(rand()%2);
                        SourcesPos[i][2] = -float(sin(theta));

                        alSourcefv(Sources[i], AL_POSITION, SourcesPos[i] );

                        alSourcePlay(Sources[i]);
                    }
            }
        }
        getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'd try this code, and if it works then maybe your question "Is it possible to play back sound positional with OpenAl on the iPhone?" Will be answered. I'm not sure because I haven't done mobile development, but I think it'd be a good starting point. Much respect to MindCode. You'll have to replace the wav files with something else to test it (and not hardcode it like I did).

Comment: Thanks man! Even if alut is not supported on iOS after reworking my code based on your example I fond my mistake. It was really dumb, one variable had to be exchanged :D In Sample::load() AL_FORMAT_STEREO16 has to replaced with 'format' which was computed from the previous function. That's why it wasn't positional!

Comment: Ooops! Completely forgot about that with ALUT and iOS.